# Unable to set HTML custom attribute value using Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

I have a checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox"  doublecheck="@item.isReusable">
```

and the `item.isReusable` is a bool field. Value inside it is either True or false. But when the HTML gets rendered I always get the result like this

```
<input type="checkbox" doublecheck="doublecheck">
```

What can be the reason I am unable to set True/False as the value of my custom attribute `doublecheck` ? And how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `HtmlHelper`,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public bool isReusable { get; set; } = true;
        
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.CheckBox("checkbox1", new { doublecheck = Model.isReusable ,value=false})
```

Generated Html:
[image]